# Уничтожение объектов

Tags: c++, qt

main.cpp

```
#include "Manager.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication *application = new QApplication(argc, argv);

    Manager *manager = new Manager;

    return application->exec();
}
```

Manager.h

```
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H

#include "MainWindow.h"

class Manager
{
public:
    Manager();
private:
    MainWindow *mainWindow;
};
#endif // MANAGER_H
```

Manager.cpp

```
#include "Manager.h"

Manager::Manager()
{
    mainWindow = new MainWindow(0);
    mainWindow->show();
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>

class QPushButton;

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent);
    QPushButton *buttonStart;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "QPushButton"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    buttonStart = new QPushButton(this);  
}
```

В классе Manager буду создавать объекты классов Qt, экземпляр класса Manager создается в главной функции и будет только один(manager). Уничтожится ли объект manager и созданные в его классе объекты Qt при закрытии программы? Я имею ввиду не только кнопку, но и другие объекты которые добавятся...

Comment: Сами по себе, без вызова деструктора?

Comment: Ну, при закрытии программы вообще все уничтожится. Вообще, когда вы создаете элемент так: `buttonStart = new QPushButton(this);`, то уничтожать его в деструкторе родителя не нужно, он уничтожится автоматически, при уничтожении родителя.

Comment: @andy.37: Ну, уничтожится-то да, но деструкторы leak'нутых объектов не отработают.

Comment: @VladD, их деструкторы вызовутся сами, их не нужно вызывать явно через `delete` при определенных условиях - см. ответ.

Comment: Деструктор объекта `manager` не будет вызван в данном случае. Необходимо явно определять delete, либо использовать локальную переменную: `Manager manager; return application->exec();`

Comment: @PavelParshin, причем второе явно предпочтительнее, т.к. я слабо представляю, куда тут можно впихнуть `delete`.

Comment: @andy.37: Объекты `application` и `manager` из `main` вряд ли самоудалятся. Отсюда по идее следует, что и каскадное удаление подобъектов по цепочке под вопросом. (Но я не спец в Qt, точно не знаю.)

Comment: @VladD, `manager` лучше создавать локальной переменной, а не указателем (см. выше). `application` уничтожится где-то внутри `exec`, вероятно (не копал так глубоко), это стандартный `main` Qt-шной программы.

Comment: @andy.37: Стандартный именно с `application` в куче, а не на стеке?

Comment: @VladD, да ошибаюсь, конечно, см ответ PavelParshin

Comment: @andy.37: Я реально не знаком с Qt, поэтому это был именно вопрос, а не замаскированное возражение. Но спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @VladD, Вы предельно корректны, поэтому это было понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте локальные переменные, деструкторы которых будут вызваны автоматически при выходе из функции. В вашем же случае вы динамически выделяете память под объекты `application` и `manager`, но не освобождаете ее.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication application(argc, argv);

    Manager manager;

    return application.exec();
}
```

Второй вариант:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication application(argc, argv);

    Manager* manager = new Manager();

    int status = application.exec();

    delete manager;
    return status;
}
```

Третий вариант (при условии использования C++11):

```
#include <memory>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication application(argc, argv);

    auto manager = std::unique_ptr(new Manager()); // Либо другой умный указатель.

    return application.exec();
}
```

Comment: Поправьте `return application.exec();`

Comment: @andy.37 да, спасибо.

Comment: Кстати, если очень нужны указатели и динамическое выделение памяти, то можно сделать так: 
`Manager* manager = new Manager(); int status = application.exec(); delete manager; return status;`

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
   MyWidget (QWidget *parent=0) : QWidget(parent) {
       b1 = new QPushButton("b1", this);
       b2 = new QPushButton("b2");
       this->layout()->addWidget(b2); // некорректно и не скомпилируется но суть ясна.
       b3 = new QPushButton("b3"); // не добавляев его в layout, вообще никак не связываем с this
   }
   ~MyWidget() {
      // delete b1; - не нужно, Qt сам удалит
      // delete b2; - не нужно, Qt сам удалит
      delete b3; // - нужно, т.к. b3 не связан с MyWidget.
   }
private:
   QPushButton *b1;
   QPushButton *b2;
   QPushButton *b3;
}
```